# Java AWT graphics for loop grid

Tags: java, for-loop, awt

I need some help with creating a grid in java AWT. You get a certain number of columns, for now let's say 13.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
{
    Graphics.fillRect((i * 15), 10, 10, 10);
}
```

Graphics takes in x, y, width, height.

This results in;

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

This will put all cubes next to each other. This is not what I want. I need the y position to go down by 15 pixels every time 4 cubes have been drawn.

The result would be

```
XXXX
XXXX
XXXX
X
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: [`Graphics#fillRect(x, y, width, height)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))...?

Comment: Yes, sorry will edit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have to increment the `x`, and every time you reach the limit, you bring the x back to zero, and increase the `y`:

```
// These should be constants, defined at the class level
public static final int NUM_RECTANGLES = 13;
public static final int NUM_COLUMNS = 4;

// And your loop
int col = 0;
int row = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < NUM_RECTANGLES; i++)
{
    Graphics.fillRect((col * 15), 10 + (row * 15), 10, 10);
    col++;
    if( col == NUM_COLUMNS ) {
        col = 0;
        row++;
    }
}
```

As you see, after each rectangle, you increase the column. If you get to the limit for the column (remember you started from 0), you move to the next line. This means the column is again 0, and the row is increased.

Of course, if your `13` and `4` are actually parameters, ignore my remark about constants.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a double `for()` loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        Graphics.fillRect(i * 15, j * 15, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

This will create a 4x4 grid of rectangles. If you want to limit it to a 4x4-like grid that only has 1 rectangle in the last row, which it seems like you want, use `j < ((i == 3) ? 1 : 4)` as your termination condition in the second for loop, or use a simple if condition like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        Graphics.fillRect(i * 15, j * 15, 10, 10);
        if(i == 3) break;
    }
}
```

### edit: Generic Solution

```
int nRow, nCol, nLastCol;

//Initialize values

for(int i = 0; i < cRow; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < ((i == nRow - 1) ? nLastCol : nCol); j++) {
        Graphics.fillRect(i * 15, j * 15, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, there is my problem, this will alway give an even grid. and would never draw something like 13.

Comment: It should be if `if (i == 3) break;` since `i == 4` is never reached. I've edited my post accordingly.

Comment: This only works if you know how many rows there are going to be.  If you know the number of columns but not the number of rows then this won't work without some tweeking.

Comment: I have edited my post to include a generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set how many columns and keep track of which column you're drawing so that you can increment the row. On a side note, I also wouldn't put a magic number in the loop, instead make that a variable (just good programming practice). Something like this:

```
int numRectangles = 13;
int numColumns = 4;//set this to however many columns you need
int currentRow = 1;//start at one, not zero
int tempRow = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < numRectangles; i++)
{
    Graphics.fillRect((i * 15), (tempRow * 10), 10, 10);
    currentRow++;
    if(currentRow > numColumns) {
        currentRow = 1;
        tempRow++;
    }
}
```

Comment: @KatsuKokushi I just fixed it, sorry about that.